# holomorphic function with integral coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, fourier-series

I'm trying to prove that an holomorphic function on $\{Z, |Z|<1\}$ and continuous on $\{Z, |Z|\leq 1\}$ with coefficients in $\mathbb Z$ is polynomial. I have tried to establish some partial reciprocal theorems of the radial Abel theorem in ordre to prove it but it hasn't be useful.

Comment: $f(z)=\frac{1}{z-2}$ is holomorphic and continuous on the sets you have, it's not polynomial?

Comment: No, $ \frac{1}{z-2} = -\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} (\frac{z}{2})^n $
Those coefficients are not in $ \mathbb Z $.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. Then the answer below is what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$, then for every $r\in(0,1)$.
$$
a_n=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=r}\frac{f(z)\,dz}{z^{n+1}},
$$
But as $f$ is continuous in the closed disc, then $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{f(z)\,dz}{z^{n+1}}$ is also well-defined and 
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{f(z)\,dz}{z^{n+1}}=\lim_{r\to 1^-}\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=r}\frac{f(z)\,dz}{z^{n+1}}=a_n.
$$
But
$$
a_n=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{f(z)\,dz}{z^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{2\pi }\int_0^{2\pi}f(\mathrm{e}^{i\vartheta})\,\mathrm{e}^{-in\vartheta}\,d\vartheta,
$$
and the right-hand side tends to zero, as $n$ tends to infinity since $\mathrm{e}^{-in\vartheta}/\sqrt{2\pi}$, $n\in\mathbb N$, is orthonormal in $L^2[0,2\pi]$. Thus, if the $a_n$'s are integers, they will vanish eventually.

Comment: Yes but there you are using the radial abel theorem, and tu use it, you need to know that $ \sum a_n z^n $ converge for $ | z | $ =1 ...

Comment: I think that we need to prove that $ \exists z_0 \in C(0,1) / \lim_{z \rightarrow z_0 radially} \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_n z^n = + \infty $   if f isn't a polynom on $ \{ z / |z|<1 \} $